# .htaccess RewriteRule Rewrite Condition with query string, but not adding query string to final url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have to following rewrite rule:

1. The query string must begin with *choice1* or *choice2*
2. The query string contains only one other value
3. The domain should be path of the final url
4. The final url should not contain the query string.
5. The final url should contain the two values of the query string in its path

I have this so far (with help from here):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(choice1|choice2)&([^&.]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\..+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/%1/%2/%3 [L,NE,R=302]
```

The conditions work fine.
**But the final url does not contain the values of the query string (%1 and %2). 
Also the query string is appended, although I do not use the QSA-Flag.**

Some examples:

```
first-domain.de?choice1&abc => https://www.mysite.de/link/choice1/abc/first-domain
first-domain.de?choice2&xyz => https://www.mysite.de/link/choice2/xyz/first-domain
second-domain.de?choice1&ttt => https://www.mysite.de/link/choice1/ttt/second-domain
second-domain.de?choice2&xyz => https://www.mysite.de/link/choice2/xyz/second-domain
```

Comment: Can you please add some examples of source and target URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^(choice1|choice2)&([^&#]+)#(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mysite.de/link/%1/%2/%3? [L,NE,R=302]
```

Reason of using `%{QUERY_STRING}#%{HTTP_HOST}` in a single condition is that we can only use most recent `RewriteCond` for capturing values `%1`, `%2`, `%3` etc.